# Display images within specific size

Tags: php, html

I have an issue for displaying images within specific size in php. In here I used the foreach loop. Anyone help me to solve this.

Here is the code,

```
    <?php
function scrape_insta_hash($tag) {
    $insta_source = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'.$tag.'/'); // instagrame tag url
    $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
    $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]); 
    $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
    return $insta_array; // this return a lot things print it and see what else you need
}

    $tag = 'paris'; // tag for which ou want images 
    $results_array = scrape_insta_hash($tag);
    //$limit = 7; 
    $limit = 15; // provide the limit thats important because one page only give some images.
    $image_array= array(); // array to store images.
    for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 

        $latest_array = $results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges'][$i]['node'];
        $image_data  = '<img src="'.$latest_array['thumbnail_src'].'">'; // thumbnail and same sizes 
        //$image_data  = '<img src="'.$latest_array['display_src'].'">'; actual image and different sizes 
        array_push($image_array, $image_data);
    }


    foreach ($image_array as $image) {
        echo $image;

        }

?>
```

Comment: What is inside $image_array?

Comment: what does $image contains? If it is HTML Code, edit the HTML code (or CSS).

Comment: Could you please explain more? please try to add code and screenshot if possible, Explain the code a bit more so that it is easier to understand about your desired output

Comment: From here it is displaying images only. But I need to get into specific size.

Comment: I re-edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loop with image **height** and **width** attribute that you want

```
for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 

        $latest_array = $results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges'][$i]['node'];
        $image_data  = '<img height="150" width="150" src="'.$latest_array['thumbnail_src'].'">'; // thumbnail and same sizes 
        //$image_data  = '<img src="'.$latest_array['display_src'].'">'; actual image and different sizes 
        array_push($image_array, $image_data);
    }
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you.

Comment: Great, Happy Coding !!

Comment: @Octavia, That answer to another question has been deleted by moderators. Please accept this answer as accepted.